# converting csv to xslx and adding column to the front with file name values in it using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to convert csv files to excel files, and adding column to the front,
with newly added column I want to fill it with the file name of that worksheet until the last row where data exist in that worksheet the code I am using is

```
Sub CSVtoXlsx()

 Dim CSVfolder As String
 Dim XlsFolder As String
 Dim fname As String
 Dim wBook As Workbook

 lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
 strAddress2 = "A3:A" & lastRow
 wbName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

 CSVfolder = "C:\csvfolder\"
 XlsFolder = "C:\xlsFolder\"

 fname = Dir(CSVfolder & "*.csv")

 Do While fname <> ""
    Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(CSVfolder & fname, Format:=6, Delimiter:=",")
    wBook.SaveAs XlsFolder & Replace(fname, ".csv", ""), xlWorkbookDefault
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Range(strAddress2).Value = Left(wbName, InStrRev(wbName, ".") - 1)
    wBook.Close False
 fname = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

this code successfully convert csv file to xslx format and also add a new column to the front of it, but it is not filling the newly added column with the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Once you **Open** the new workbook, it becomes the ActiveWorkbook.  You save it, and then settup the first column, and then close it without saving it again.

Comment: ok I tried saving it by typing ActiveWorkbook.Save but still no luck